# Converting a plane from Cartesian to Parametric

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equations of the following plane in both cartesian and parametric form:

The plane through the point $(1,4,5)$ and perpendicular to the vector $(7,1,4)$.

So far, I have obtained the cartesian form, which is:
$$7x + 4y + z =31.$$

How do I change this to the parametric form:
$r = r_0 + s\vec u + t\vec v$ where $s$ and $t$ are real numbers?

Answer (score 1):

you need to find two more points which lie on the plane, for example $B(4,0,3)$ and $C(0,7,3)$
then your parametric equation will be $$\underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\4\\5\end{matrix}\right)+\lambda\left[\left(\begin{matrix}1\\4\\5\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}4\\0\\3\end{matrix}\right)\right]+\mu\left[\left(\begin{matrix}1\\4\\5\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}0\\7\\3\end{matrix}\right)\right]$$
$$\Rightarrow \underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\4\\5\end{matrix}\right)+\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}-3\\4\\2\end{matrix}\right)+\mu\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-3\\2\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: @user263058 Notice that $A,B,C$ must **not** be collinear!

Comment: indeed, and note also this is just one of many possible formulations of this equation